# Term describing emotional agreement with an argument regardless of the validity of the argument itself?

Tags: single-word-requests

I was wondering if there is a word that describes when someone emotionally agrees with someones argument regardless of whether the argument actually is a valid argument or not.

For example a fan of sports team X might get excited and agree with someone's argument that "Sports team Y is terrible" regardless of any evidence they give to support that claim.

The online Cambridge definition of 'jingoism' is close, but describes only nationalistic arguments.  It's not a potshot, or straw man because those describe the argument and also because the word I'm looking for could allow for a rigorous, and true argument, but the reason the person agrees with it is not based on the argument but their allegiances.

Comment: How does your request line up with the rhetorical appeals of *logos*, *ethos*, and *pathos*? Would you describe your person as influenced primarily by appeals to *pathos*?

Comment: Aristotle defined three methods of persuasion: *logos* (by logic), *pathos* (by emotion), and *ethos* (by authority/credibility of the speaker or some third-party). This sounds like it could be either of the last two.

Comment: The type of argument is really irrelevant, if the listener thinks the conclusion of the argument lines up with what they believe then they will agree with it emotionally without really considering if the premises are valid and lead to the conclusion.

Answer (score 0):

Granted it's two words not one, but I was thinking that fan sounds ***emotionally biased***.  And lo and behold there is a [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emotional_bias) on the theme:

An emotional bias is a distortion in cognition and decision making due to emotional factors.

> As examples, a person might be inclined:
>
> to attribute negative judgements to neutral events or objects;
>   to believe something that has a positive emotional effect, that gives a pleasant feeling, even if there is evidence to the contrary;
>   to be reluctant to accept hard facts that are unpleasant and give mental suffering.

The fan of sports team X is guilty of the last two.